# Command line runner loads CPU after restart Android Studio 3

Tags: cpu, android-studio-3.0

Every time when I restarted Android studio 3 this process starts load CPU to 100%

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: whats your problem i dont get your point

Comment: strange process 'command line runner' loads CPU to 100% and i need close it by manual

Comment: Same issue here, Did you find solution?

Comment: No, i still have it.